# Are hats in fashion this year?

Tags: discussion

Last year, Stack Exchange ran [Winter Bash 2015](http://winterbash2015.stackexchange.com/), in which users earned hats which they proudly displayed upon their gravatar. There was a leaderboard of hatters, mad or not:

[image: 2015 top hat wearers]

It's that time of the year again and we get to choose whether we want to do it this time around. Because of the popularity enjoyed by the previous years' bashes, all sites now opt-in by default unless the community decides to opt out.

What are hats, I hear you ask. Well, hats are kinda like ephemeral badges. You can choose to have one displayed over your avatar and you win them by certain actions on the webpage. Users can turn off hats on a per-user basis, so if you're against them for any reason, you can disable the feature and not see your hats nor those of the users who have opted in. As far as you are concerned, the hats will not exist.

Unless we choose to opt out, the event will run  from 19 December 2016 up to and including 08 January 2017. After that, all the hats go away into Last Year's Hat Bin. More information will be available on the [2016 Winter Bash page](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/).

If we want to opt out, we have to decide to do so by Tuesday, 13 December 2016. So, do we like hats or hate hats?

Comment: Not much information on that Winter Bash page right now...

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Upvote this answer to say a big

## YES to hats!

Hats are always in fashion!

Comment: Yea! Where's the hats??

Comment: @Hack-R Dec 19 will be when hats come!

Comment: I could use a nice warm one about now.

Answer (score 1):

Upvote this answer to say a big

## NO to hats!

Hats? That's so 2015!

Comment: People seem to downvote *YES to hats!* rather than upvoting this one, so I guess you might as well delete it.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev actually, this currently has 7 upvotes and 7 downvotes, while the yes only has 2 downvotes.

Comment: Wow, I totally missed it! Guess I just couldn't imagine someone hating hats... Anyway, a single item to vote for/against would have been less ambiguous IMO. Now I have to resist the urge to downvote the answer I don't like and make my vote count as two.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev What is this "resist"? Vote early, vote often!

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev Of course you can take the advantage of a double vote!

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev Don't worry; I for one hope that our Hat Overlords are sufficiently knowledgable to check the actual vote counts and not just the net total before making a decision. :-)

Comment: Clearly, you're not bald. If you were, you'd understand why we need hats.

Comment: Bald or not, in my neck of the woods it's currently cold enough to definitely require a hat!